# Get text value selected by attribute value in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

In SQL how to get the text value - "2/9/2015" by using attribute value "EffectiveDate":

```
<xml>
    <entity>
        <sdfs>
            <df name="EffectiveDate">2/9/2015</df>                        
        </sdfs>
    </entity>
</xml>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? The official docs explain how to access XML data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x XML = N'
<xml>
    <entity>
        <sdfs>
            <df name="EffectiveDate">2/9/2015</df>
        </sdfs>
    </entity>
</xml>'

SELECT @x.value('(xml/entity/sdfs/df[@name="EffectiveDate"])[1]', 'varchar(10)')
```